# Navigation between components using v-navigation-drawer using Vue JS 3 and Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-navigation-drawer

I am trying to use the documentation for navigation drawer as per the example below.

[Vuetify Playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

I see several examples using a vue-router for changing navigation between components. However, I am looking for an example without a router.

I did look around documentation in vuetifyjs.com but couldn't find anything related. Looking for an example how to navigate between components WITHOUT a router.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/

Comment: I think you're looking for [Props Declaration.](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html)

Comment: Please look at this example below. Passing props as an attribute is for other components. I am looking more around the sample listed above. [link]
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/navigation-drawers/

Comment: Navigating between components isn't a topic related to the Vuetify library.  It's much more general than that.  SPAs by their nature are _single page_.  Any "navigation" is an illusion of dynamic programming.  If you don't want to use Vue Router, which is a great library, you'll have to implement your own solution.  the official [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/routing.html#simple-routing-from-scratch) give a simple routing example using the dynamic `<component>` element.

Comment: @yoduh, Thanks for the link above.This will be a SPA application which has to be integrated into sharepoint environment. I can't use Vue Router as the user experience is NOT that great when integrated with Sharepoint.

Comment: You may be interested in Nuxt SSG